# The jumping times of a càdlàg process are stopping times.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Protter first proves this theorem:

> Let $X$ be an adapted càdlàg stochastic process, and let $A$ be a
>   closed set. Then the random variable:
>
> $T(\omega)=\inf\{t: X_t(\omega)\in A \text{ or } X_{t^-} \in A\}$,
>
> is a stopping time.

Then he says that it follows from this theorem :

> If $K>0$ is a positive number, then:
>
> $T^1 = \inf\{t >0 : |\Delta X_t|>k\}$
>
> $T^{n+1}=\inf\{t >T^n : |\Delta X_t|>k\}$, are stopping times.

I've tried proving this from the above theorem, but I am not able to do it.

**attempt regarding $T_1$**

I need to show that $\{\omega : T^1(\omega) \le t\}\in \mathcal{F}_t$. If an $\omega$ is in this set, then since a càdlàg process only have a finite number of jumps larger than $k/2$ in the interval $[0,t+1]$, we must have that at least one jump $>k$ occurring  in the interval $[0,t]$. My guess in using the theorem is that A maybe should be $[-k,k]$ ? But I don't see how this works?

**attempt regarding induction**

I also have a problem with the induction part. Lets say that we have that $T^1,\ldots,T^n$ are stopping times. Why is then $T^{n+1}$ a stopping time? I have that $\{T^{n} \le t\}\subset\{T^{n+1} \le t\}$. But my guess is that I must write $\{T^{n} \le t\}\cup C=\{T^{n+1} \le t\}$, where $C \in \mathcal{F}_t$. But I can't really see what $C$ this must be.

Do you see how to show this? I have seen this argument used in many books, maybe it is very easy to show. Is there a book that shows the argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key point is the following lemma which has nothing to do with probability theory, but is just elementary "deterministic" calculus.

> **Lemma:** Let $f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a càdlàg function and fix $M>0$ and $0 \leq T_0<T_1<\infty$. Then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. There exists $t \in (T_0,T_1]$ such that $|\Delta f(t)|>M$.
> 2. There exists $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there are $u,v \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (T_0,T_1+k^{-1}]$ such that $|u-v| \leq k^{-1}$ and $|f(u)-f(v)|>M+\frac{1}{K}$.

Applying this lemma with $T_0 =0$ and $T_1 = t$ and $f(t) := X_t(\omega)$, we find

$$\{T^1\leq t\} = \bigcup_{K \geq 1} \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{\substack{u,v \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,t+k^{-1}) \\ |u-v| \leq k^{-1}}} \{|X_u-X_v| > M+1/K\}.$$

Since the right-hand side is a countable union/intersection, this shows $\{T^1 \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_{t+}$ and so $T^1$ is an $(\mathcal{F}_{t+})$-stopping time. If the filtration is right-continuous, then $T^1$ is an $(\mathcal{F}_t)_t$-stopping time.

Similarly, it holds that

$$\{T^{n+1} \leq t\} = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,t)} \{T^n \leq q\} \cap \bigg(\bigcup_{K \geq 1} \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{\substack{u,v \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (q,t+k^{-1}) \\ |u-v| \leq k^{-1}}} \{|X_u-X_v|>M+1/K\} \bigg).$$

Again, this is a countable union/intersection and therefore $T^{n+1}$ is an $(\mathcal{F}_{t+})$-stopping time.

Comment: Thank you very muich, this was very nice! Is there a book where this lemma and this technique is used? I would have liked a book where it is used, becase it seems like a lot of texts use that this and this are stopping times, without actually showing it.

Comment: @user119615 No, sorry, I don't have a reference. I agree with you that many authors use such results without proving them - which is a pity.

Comment: I see, thanks anyway, this was very nice!

Comment: The lemma doesn't quite seem right to me. I suspect that somewhere there wants to be a weak instead of strict inequality or vice versa. For example, if $f(x) = x$ for $x \in [0,1)$ and $f(x) = x+1$ for $x \geq 1$ then setting $M=1, T_0 = 0$ and $T_1 \geq 2$ gives that $f$ is càdlàg, does not satisfy 1. (the only jump is of size exactly $1$) and does satisfy 2. since for all $u > 1, v<1$, $f(u) - f(v) > 1$.

Comment: @RhysSteele You are right; I hope it's okay now.

Comment: @saz How do we prove the claim? Don't get it right now: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3028322/equivalent-condition-for-the-existence-of-a-t%e2%88%88t-0-t-1-with-ft-lim-s%e2%86%92t

Comment: @0xbadf00d The way you are asking the question doesn't make me enthusiastic to answer it .... you don't show any effort and certainly you **do** have some thoughts on the problem (perhaps you can prove one of the implications or there is  particular point where you are stuck or...)

Comment: @saz I've added my thoughts to the question. (Oh, and I've got problems to see how you obtain your equation for $\left\{T^1\le t\right\}$ ... somehow frustrating.)

Comment: @0xbadf00d Why that? It's just a reformulation of the second statement of the lemma ... "$\bigcap$" reads "for all" and "$\bigcup$" reads "there exists.

Comment: I think right-continuity of the filtration may not be required, by considering separately the event of a discontinuity exactly at $t$ and of a discontinuity "around all rationals" before $t$; similar in spirit to the proof of Protter, Theorem I.4

Answer (score 0):

I think the above answer still doesn't solve your problem, namely using the above theorem to prove e.g. $T^1$ is a stopping time.

I have exactly the same problem, so I want to give it a try and maybe we can prove it together.

The fact that the set of discontinuities of a cadlag process is finite is very well known. While this is a statement about the time variable $t$, $\Lambda$ in Protter's Theorem 4 concerns the space of $X_t(\omega)$. However, notice that the a.s.-finiteness of $\{t>0:|\Delta X_t|>1/n\}$ implies $\{X_t:|\Delta X_t|>1/n\}$ and $\{X_{t-}:|\Delta X_t|>1/n\}$ are also finite, and hence closed, a.s. However, Theorem 4 requires closedness, not a.s.-closedness. Can we attempt a proof along these lines?

Comment: Actually, the above is not true unless we first consider $t\in[0,t_0]$ only. So, another idea keeping that in mind: Because "a.s.-closedness" doesn't do it, how about looking at $\{(t,\omega): |\Delta X_t|>1/n\}$. We can't reasonably expect this new set to be finite because we're now considering all $\omega$ at once. Conjecture: Maybe this set still doesn't have any accumulation points, which would make it closed and we could apply that Theorem 4.