# Measurability of the sum of measurable functions $(X_t)_{t \in I}$ ranging over a random index set $N$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Assume I have a collection of real-valued measurable functions $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ on the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$. Let $N:\Omega \rightarrow 2^\Omega$ such that for every $\omega \in \Omega$, the value $|N(\omega)| < \infty$, where $|\cdot|$ now denotes the cardinality of a set. If I look at the function $S:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$S(\omega):= \sum_{i \in N(\omega)}X_i(\omega)$$
for $\omega \in \Omega$, can I somehow deduce that **$S$ is measurable** as a function from $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ ?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You would probably need some conditions on the measurability of the function $(i,\omega) \to X_i(\omega)$? Write $S(\omega) = \int_I X_i(\omega) 1_{N(\omega)}(i) d |\cdot|(i)$, i you will excuse the gross notation.

Comment: @copper.hat would RCLL suffice?

Comment: What does RCLL mean?

Comment: @copper.hat oh yes sorry. I mean that I would impose that $I=[0,1]$ and the trajectories of the process $X$ would be RCLL (right continuous with left limits)

Answer (score 1):

Not without some sort of measurability condition on $N$. Exactly what condition that would be I don't know, but some condition is needed:

Say $X_0=0$, $X_1=1$. Say $E\subset\Omega$ is not measurable, and define $$N(\omega)=\begin{cases}\{0\},&(\omega\in E),
\\\{0,1\},&(\omega\notin E).\end{cases}$$

Comment: Actually the OP wants to prove [this statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2960830/36150)... not sure why (s)he doesn't care to explain his/her motivation.

Comment: @saz "Actually the OP wants to prove this statement..." what makes you think so?

Comment: Okay, let's say I suspect it; it was certainly part of the OPs motivation to ask this question. My comment was just meant as a side remark; sometimes I do not understand why people to not take their time to explain their motivation....

Comment: @saz I hadn't noticed that the OP was the same on the two questions - yes, that makes your conjecture quite plausible.